# IONIC CORS preflight has invalid HTTP

Tags: typescript, post, http-headers, cors, ionic3

I'm trying to make a request on my ionic app to my server.
I enabled cors on the server. When on ionic serve --lab:  I make my request, it doesn't work. The GET requests work, but the POST does not.

```
  register(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
    var header = new Headers();
    header.append("Accept", "application/json");
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/json" );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });

    var body = {
      name: username,
      email: email,
      password: password
    };

    var senderBody = JSON.stringify(body);

    console.log(body, senderBody)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post("http://54.233.195.52:8080/user_parent", senderBody, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data)
        }, error => {
          console.log(error)
          reject(error)
        });
    });
  }
```

And I call it like this:

```
  register(){
    this.authPrvd.register(this.name,this.email,this.password)
    .then(value => {
      console.log(value);
    }, reason =>{
      console.log(reason)
    })
  }
```

I expected to get a json as result like:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "naaame",
    "email": "emaaail",
    "password": "<encrypted password>",
    "facebook_id": "",
    "address_postal": "",
    "address_street": "",
    "address_number": 0,
    "address_complement": "",
    "cpf": "",
    "rg": "",
    "phone1": "",
    "phone2": "",
    "profile_image_url": "",
    "extra_info": "",
    "created_at": "2017-12-11T02:18:42.862478082Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-12-11T02:18:42.862478082Z"
}
```

And the request does work with postman.
But it doesnt work when ionic serve

I tried using the chrome extension to Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

and my cors is configured on the server:
(server in go(lang))

```
func SetDBtoContext(db *gorm.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, Origin")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")

        c.Set("DB", db)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

The errors the console give are

> OPTIONS http://54.233.195.52:8080/user_parent 404 (Not Found) Failed
>   to load http://54.233.195.52:8080/user_parent: Response for preflight
>   has invalid HTTP status code 404

checking the console i get:

[image]

**EDIT: For some reason the urlencoded works, but json does not**

Answer (score 1):

So I found out what happened for anyone who has this sort of problem.
I had to Create a response to the request of method OPTION also which has in it's headers the allow headers method. Something like this

```
v1.OPTIONS("/users", OptionsUser)      // POST
v1.OPTIONS("/users/:id", OptionsUser)  // PUT, DELETE



func OptionsUser(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE,POST, PUT")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    c.Next()
}
```

extracted from: https://medium.com/@etiennerouzeaud/how-to-create-a-basic-restful-api-in-go-c8e032ba3181

Thing is: angular and ionic http basic method create a preflight of type OPTION before sending POST. I just had to handle it...

Answer (score 0):

All i do is handle the OPTIONS Request as well as below-

```
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/rpc", Preflight).Methods("OPTIONS")

func Preflight(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    // return "OK"
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("OK")

}
```

and in any GET request add

```
 w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```